# Removing rows from an excel file using JExcel API

Tags: java, jxl, jexcelapi

I am trying to delete duplicate rows from my excel file. I have the following line of code.
After I run the code it creates modified_excel.xls. However I get an error when opening this file "unsupported file format"

```
Workbook sourceDocument = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\source.xls"));
WritableWorkbook writableTempSource = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\excel\\modified_excel.xls"), sourceDocument);
WritableSheet sourceSheet = writableTempSource.getSheet(0);
String previousContent = "";
for (int i = 7; i < sourceSheet.getRows(); i++) {
     String currentContent = sourceSheet.getCell(0, i).getContents();
     if(!currentContent.equals(previousContent)){
         sourceSheet.removeRow(i);
     }
     previousContent = currentContent;
}
writableTempSource.close();
sourceDocument.close();
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`apache.poi`](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) Java API to work with Excel and other office documentation tools?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things I think which can help this situation

1)

```
writableTempSource.write();
```

This should come just before closing `writableTempSource`.  If you were to comment out the for block, you would see you still have a file created of an "unsupported format".  This line will fix that.

2)

I do believe you may have issue with the `i` variable in the for loop.  Consider this.  You are checking `sourceSheet.getRows()` on each iteration.  However, if rows are getting deleted, then this value changes each time a deletion occurs.  The result is that you may be skipping lines which is not necessary what you want.  Java naturally provides this on for loops with `ConcurrentModificationException`, however in the magical kingdom of API-Land, it looks like you are not protected from doing this sort of thing.